# How to insert multiple integer values in single cell of a particular column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate-functions

I have the table as follows

userid(primary key)

history(integer)

in the history cell I need to insert with multiple values in a single cell which is of type integer example -

```
1 history:(1,4,6)
2 history:(2,7,9)
```

also I have to update the values like  before -> history(1,4,6) after ->history(1,4,5,7)

Comment: What is a "cell"?  That is not a database term.

Comment: history's data type is integer. How do you expect to store strings?

Comment: in my view cell means particular column of a row

Comment: This is not a great design. How many values do you want to store in the column? It won't scale up well. I would suggest you set up a 1:N relationship with another table to store the history of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to insert with multiple values in a single cell which is of type integer example

You just can't do that. An integer value is just that: a single integer value stored in a given column.

If you want to associate several values to a given `user_id`, then this is a one-to-many relationship. You would typically represent that as a separate table, with one row per `(user_id, history)` tuple, like so:

```
user_id     history
1           1
1           4
1           6
2           2
2           7
2           9
```

The primary key of this table would be made of the combination of both columns, with the `user_id` column being a foreign key to the `users` table.

Then, you can generate a comma separataed-list, if that's what you want, with an aggregation query:

```
select user_id, group_concat(history) all_history
from user_history
group by user_id
```

You can then bring the original table with a `join`:

```
select u.*, uh.all_history
from users u
inner join (
    select user_id, group_concat(history) all_history
    from user_history
    group by user_id
) uh on u.user_id = uh.user_id
```

Comment: by storing in the other table such that upon retrieving we have to join the table that's what you meant right?

Comment: @SriHarshaDamarla: yes, that's that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `group_concat()`:

```
select userid, group_concat(history)
from t
group by userid;
```

Comment: how can I insert to the table ?

Comment: @SriHarshaDamarla . . . Into *what* table?  You would use either `insert` or `create table as`.  But that seems utterly unnecessary when you can just run the query.